# If $C ⊆ D$ are subsets of $Y$ , then $f^{−1}(C) ⊆ f^{−1}(D)$, and $f: X \rightarrow Y$.

Tags: functions

If $C ⊆ D$ are subsets of $Y$ , then $f^{−1}(C) ⊆ f^{−1}(D)$, and $f: X \rightarrow Y$.

Notes that $f^{-1}$ is referring to the preimage.

What I have so far:

$f^{-1}(C):= \{x \in X: f(x) \in C\}$

$f^{-1}(D): = \{x \in X: f(x) \in D\}$.

$\forall y \in C, y \in D$. Since $f(x) = y$, all the $x$ values in $f^{-1}(c)$ must also be included in $f^{-1}(D)$, since the mapped $y$ values of $C ⊆ D$.

Comment: Come to think of it, this is pretty much complete as-is. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

By definition $f^{-1}(C)$ are things that map to things in $C$, but then $C\subseteq D$, so if you map into $C$ you also map into $D$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $C\subset D$,
$$f^{-1}(C)=\{x\mid f(x)\in C\subset D\}\subset \{x\mid f(x)\in D\}=f^{-1}(D).$$

Answer (score 0):

$C\subseteq D$ tells us that every element of $C$ is an element of $D$, so:

- any $x$ that is sent by $f$ to an element of $C$ is sent to an element of $D$.

This can also be stated as:

- for any $x\in f^{-1}(C)$ we have $x\in f^{-1}(D)$

or as:

- $f^{-1}(C)\subseteq f^{-1}(D)$